# How configure an Entity so that Navigation property can be Included in queries but it will be excluded from change tracking

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5

Consider following many to many scenario:

```
public class Order
{
   public int OrderId { get; set; }
   public ICollection<OrderItem> Items { get; set; }
}
public class Product
{
   public int ProductId { get; set; }
}
public class OrderItem 
{
   public int OrderId { get; set; }
   public int ItemId { get; set; }

   public Product Product { get; set; } // I want this navigation property to be ignored when saving order
}
```

I need to be able to Include `OrderItem.Item` navigation property

```
Order order = dbContext.Orders
  .Include(o => o.Items).ThenInclude(o => o.Item)
  .Find(id)
```

but I also want it to be untracked by DB context. That means, when I add some Order.Items:

```
void AddItem(Product product) 
{
  order.Items.Add(new OrderItem 
  {
    ProductId = product.Id,
    Product = product
  }
}
```

and call `dbContext.SaveChanges()`, any values of `OrderItem.Product` property are simply ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AsNotracking to tell the entity framework that you will be responsible for tracking queries.

your query will be the following:

```
var order = dbContext.Orders.AsNoTracking()
.Include(o => o.Items).ThenInclude(o => o.Item)
.Find(id);
```

If you want to save an order without products, you only need to track the change for orders

```
public async Task AddAsync(Order entity)
{
   context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Added;
   await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```